# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, server

Why am i getting this error?

```
shibly@mybox:~/blog$ rails server
/home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/shibly/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/shibly/.gem/ruby/2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the exactly same issue. I'm running ruby 2.2.4 with rails 4.2.5 on ubuntu.

Comment: try sudo apt-get install nodejs

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You should run following command to install NodeJS in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

or run this for OSX

```
brew install nodejs
```

Uglifier is a JS wrapper and it needs a JS runtime running or JS interpreter. I would choose to install NodeJS.

Comment: why it needs js env?

Comment: It works :) Thanks, But why we need this nodejs to be installed ?

Comment: We need a JS Runtime, @AlankarMore ;). So, NodeJS this is usually my choice, mainly because it's built on Chrome's V8 engine (https://developers.google.com/v8/). 

We have a lot of JS today at Rails. And we need an environment set to run all that stuff. That includes wrappers, runtimes/interpreters...

Comment: If installing nodejs from source, make sure the binary is installed to `/usr/bin/nodejs` where execjs expects to find it.

Comment: @MarcosSerpa Thanks! It works for me, too. And I have a question. Is the Nodejs an essential requirement for installing and using Ruby on Rails even when you're not using it directly?

Comment: @AboozarRajabi Nodejs is not an essential, but a JS runtime or interpreter is. And this is the role of NodeJS here, to our case. If not NodeJS, you'll need another JS runtime/interpreter.

Comment: For people struggling with this on Rails 2.4 (where nodejs doesn't solve the problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461977/after-ruby-2-4-upgrade-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-uglifier-bundler

Comment: Why isn't there a native Ruby JavaScript interpreter? There's one for Java. Then `uglifier` can  just depend on that gem, and `bundler` will install everything correctly the first time.

Answer (score 36):

In the default Rails Gemfile, the line for the gem 'therubyracer' is commented out. If you uncomment it, you'll get that gem and it should work.

From "[Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#starting-up-the-web-server)":

> Compiling CoffeeScript and JavaScript asset compression requires you have a JavaScript runtime available on your system, in the absence of a runtime you will see an `execjs` error during asset compilation. Usually Mac OS X and Windows come with a JavaScript runtime installed. Rails adds the `therubyracer` gem to the generated `Gemfile` in a commented line for new apps and you can uncomment if you need it. `therubyrhino` is the recommended runtime for JRuby users and is added by default to the `Gemfile` in apps generated under JRuby. You can investigate all the supported runtimes at [ExecJS](https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme).

Comment: Thanks!  This was easier and seems cleaner than relying on NodeJS.

Comment: While this answer works it eludes that you should rather have (for production) a proper execjs runtime like node.js

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with creating the db.

The problem is that the Node.js tried to install without `sudo` in the script:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```