# rails not working in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
    expertly@AECUTE ~/Documents/RUBY/timetable $ rails s
/home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/expertly/Documents/RUBY/timetable/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/expertly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

please help me for this problem.

Comment: Your title is not at clear..what does that even mean, rails inside rails

Comment: sorry bro, i very bad in english :D

Comment: consider searching for the similar question, please put some effort to find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34472412/2545197 , tons of similar issues out there.

Comment: it's awesome!! it's working already, thank a lot bro.

Comment: no problem, i am glad that it worked for you. :) all the best