# uglifier gem load error / download node.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubygems, installation, uglifier

I am getting started with Ruby on Rails, and following the steps at InstallRails... I have created the sample_app on the desktop, and now I cannot create the server.

My command

```
$ rails server
```

is answered with the following

```
...There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.  etc
```

I have read several threads here and elsewhere, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420554/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-uglifier-bundlergemrequire) and [this one](http://technotes.tt4living.com/ruby-on-rails/first-attempt-to-run-rails-server-and-got-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-uglifier)... In the latter there seems to bea solution, which I can't understand.... I cannot download node.js!  or nodejs? What is my command and directory in Gitbash to download it?

Comment: Did you try the commands in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires JS runtime.
Just install gem `therubyracer` for the JS runtime.
In the default rails Gemfile,uncomment the line for the gem 'therubyracer' which is commented out.If you dont find it add the gem to your Gemfile like

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

The gem will be installed and it should work.

Otherwise you can install node.js.

For ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

For mac

```
brew install nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks Bilash... I understand you, but I don't understand enough to execute haha...

I get an error when I put into gitbash or cmd.exe 'gem install therubyracer'...

I also tried your first method, and located what I thought was a gemfile, but I don't think it was the default rails Gemfile, as you called it.  I did not find a line with therubyracer gem which was commented in the file I found.  Where do I find the Default Gemfile? I feel like that would be easiest, but I don't know where to change that!

Comment: Okay, I am further along now... I have found and uncommented the line for 'therubyracer' in my default gemfile.  I have also run 'gem install bundler' ... but when I run 'bundle install' I get could not locate gemfile etc error...

Comment: Alright, even further now!  I found that I was not in the right directory for 'bundle install'... So I did 'cd APP_NAME' and then 'bundle install' and had a sucessful install.  I immediately entered 'rails server' and I got the same error as I started with, having to do with the uglifier gem... working on it!

Comment: I'm going in circles now.... can't install node.js and 'rails server' still yields the same error... I just want to get up and running to start tutorials!

Comment: Alright!  I am past this problem and onto the next!  Ultimately, installing node.js was the fix for the uglifier load error.  therubyracer cannot be installed on WIndows, and so my time messing around trying to make it work that way was futile, if informative haha.  Thank you for your thorough answer @bilash.saha

Comment: This might be an old post but i want to ask another relates question(i am banned here). I am new to ruby(installing it currently), then when i type ruby bin/rails server, it gave me the 'could not find gem uglifier (>= 1.3.0). And my pc doesnt have internet connection. what should i do?