# While doing rails s, I keep getting Insecure world writeable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have tried the doing the `chmod go-w user/local/bin` as the solution, but it says that the directory doesn't exist. I am using Ubuntu bash on Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/varghese/.rbenv in PATH, mode 040777
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:21: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:23:in `include'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:22:in `class_eval'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:21:in `each'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/conversion.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:22:in `require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:108:in `require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:108:in `available?'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:53:in `each'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:53:in `find'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:53:in `best_available'/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:47:in `autodetect'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/mnt/c/coursemantra/courses/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
/home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:8:in `require'
bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /mnt/c/coursemantra/courses/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/varghese/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420554/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-uglifier-bundlergemrequire)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe In your Gemfile, gem **therubyracer** is commented.
Uncomment it and run bundle install. And start server.

Comment: Thanks. But the gem therubyracer is un-commented

Comment: post your Gemfile.